# Node.js unicode issue with HTTP response body

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, utf-8, v8

The response body of HTTP requests using the native 'http' module, displays question mark characters for unicode chars, instead of their actual value. Here's the basic snippet of code that I'm running.

```
var http = require('http');
var google = http.createClient(80, 'www.google.it');
var request = google.request('GET', '/',
{
 'host': 'www.google.it',
}
  );
request.end();
request.on('response', function (response) {
  response.setEncoding('utf8');
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log(chunk);
  });
});
```

In the response there's a specific word that starts with "**Pubblicit**". Its last letter is a weird character that shows as a question mark to me. The word should be **Pubblicità**, instead it is displyed as **Pubblicit?**.

I have also tried outputting the data using `.toString()`:

```
console.log(chunk.toString());
```

or

```
console.log(chunk.toString('utf8'));
```

But I'm getting the same results.

Any idea?

Comment: Try checking `chunk.charCodeAt(chunk.length - 1)`. If it's `224` (`à`), the problem is with your console/locale.

Comment: @PabloFernandez, using Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Comment: @katspaugh I tested the `charCodeAt` using another test-case that uses the letter `é` instead, and `charCodeAt` outputs `65533` for that letter. Weird huh? I didn't try it with letter `à` because it would've required me to figure out on which index the latter was inside Google's response, but it will probably output something similar to `65533`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reason maybe that, if we do not specify a "googleKnownAsUTF8OK" user-agent on request header, google would response a html doc with content-type of ISO-8859-1(for old browsers,bots?i dont know), so decode the response buffer by "binary" is correct.

But, if we decode a buffer encoded in ISO-8859-1 by utf8, then the byte 0xe0(à) implies "form a character by 3bytes in a row", it is a malformed character in our case, so a few unexpected characters(depending on the environment) was displayed.

We may try "Mozilla/5.0" as value of user-agent. Good luck.

Answer (score 8):

I set `response.setEncoding('binary');` and it works. No idea why though.

Reference: http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/3bd3935b1f42a5f4?pli=1

Comment: This answer worked in my case, where I had this issue in Python-shell usage.

Answer (score 0):

> I set response.setEncoding('binary'); and it works. No idea why
>   though.
>
> Reference:
>   http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/3bd3935b1f42a5f4?pli=1

In my case I've got some wrong characters due to windows-1252 charset of an old webpage.

I just used encode: 'binary' in the request options and it worked!