# Get Images from IP Cam url with http authentification

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I try to place snapshots of my CCTV Cam on my Webpage/HTML page (all localy).
But the Problem is the HTTP Authentification.

```
  <img id="img1" border="0" src="http://admin:admin@192.168.178.41/tmpfs/auto.jpg">
```

This solution isn't possible because Chrome doesn't allow credentials in the URL anymore for security reasons.

Without the credentials I get a Error 401 obviously.
I tried it with an xmlHttpRequest, but the problem was the CORS which I can't activate on the ServerSide of the camera, from where I want to get the images. I already tried to disable the http authentification in the cam but the interface doesn't allows it. I don't care about the security aspect, because the cam is only used in a local network, which is protected. I also tried something with node.js

```
   var request = require('request');

var options = {  
    url: 'http://192.168.178.41/tmpfs/auto.jpg',
    auth: {
        username: 'admin',
        password: 'admin'
    }
};

request.get(options);
console.log(request.get(options));
```

Sry, I am not that expirienced with Node.js and hope you can help me with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to do this with `nodeJs` , you're sending the `request` but you're not doing anything with the result, it's available in the callback, try this :

```
const auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' password).toString('base64');

const options = {
    url : 'http://192.168.178.41/tmpfs/auto.jpg',
    headers : {
        "Authorization" : auth
    }
}

request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(body); // there's your image
});
```

you can always put the `auth` credentials in the `url` directly :

```
const options = {
    url : 'http://admin:admin@192.168.178.41/tmpfs/auto.jpg'
}

request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(body); // there's your image
});
```

Comment: ok thanks but the console log only delivers me nothing i can work with. At first I thought its base64 but it isn't.

Comment: `nothing you can work with` ? what do you have in the `console` ? what does `console.log(response)` give you ?

Comment: hmm , try `console.log(body.toString('utf-8'))`

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008157/node-js-unicode-issue-with-http-response-body I tried but changing the response doesnt change the body still UTF-8? Encoding Problems

Comment: changing the `response`  should change the body but access it with `response.body` , that link seems promissing, have you tried `response.setEncoding('binary')` ? because apparently you're receiving binaries ..

Comment: unfortunaly i cant chat yet... this is the result with response.setEncoding('binary') https://text-share.com/view/f52affe6

Answer (score 1):

You could do it easier in this case, cause the ip cam handes authentication with parameters you could easily give the path with the following flags: `?usr=admin&pwd=admin`

The result would be:

```
<img id="img1" border="0" src="http://192.168.178.41/tmpfs/auto.jpg?usr=admin&pwd=admin">
```

Sidenote, "snap.jpg" delivers the full image.